# Changing permissions to ODfB folder

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

When trying to change permissions to a ODfB folder (granted by a sharing link) from write to read, a bad request error is getting thrown:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "badArgument",
        "message": "One of the provided arguments is not acceptable.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2020-09-15T21:30:01",
            "request-id": "a43eb6a1-3c3b-49c4-bda1-5b4fd791da08",
            "client-request-id": "d8f9a715-9dac-9db7-1ac5-8d16d49630f2"
        }
    }
}
```

Request :

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/01HKVKMAZ1QBH7KJAWF5AIOO4D3P7AETV2/permissions/0cc09318-b541-4aa4-ba3d-aeca64c7d932
Content-type: application/json

{
    "roles": [
        "read"
    ]
}
```

I made sure that item id is correct, as well as permission id, autorization token in header is also fine.

Am I missing something, or does updating folder permissions granted by sharing links not work at all in Graph API?

Comment: Have you tried the above in Graph explorer and see the same result?

Comment: Yes, results are the same.

Comment: Ok let me try reproduce the issue and will update you the same.

Comment: Now its working for me and sounds like the issue is fixed... If it works, please do confirm..